# Calling webservice URLs using java

Tags: java, spring, multithreading

Hi I have a requirement of calling 20K webservice urls using java, but it is giving me heapspace issue, Kindly anyone help me in creating Multithreading on that code or are there any other way to call them.

Comment: presently I am using ingest method from predix timeseries api viz affection the performance

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Java, you might like the TimeSeries Bootstrap:
https://github.com/predixdev/timeseries-bootstrap

In Python:
https://github.com/PredixDev/predixpy

In JS, there's no SDK yet, but you can use an npm module, like `ws`.

Answer (score 1):

I have tested pythond SDK and it works fine, here is also Qt, C++ - https://github.com/IndeemaSoftware/QPredix